# Visual Studio 2010 (C#): Blank before and after * when multiplying

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatting, settings, code-formatting

I noticed a strange behavior in Visual Studio 2010 when programming C#. When I type

```
var x = 2 * 5
```

and then enter ';' VS changes the line to

```
var x = 2*5;
```

So it removes the blanks. On the other hand, if I do CTRL+X and CTRL+V in that line, the blanks are inserted again;

```
var x = 2 * 5;
```

This is quite annoying when using tools like SVN, since it makes tracking **actual** changes in the code more difficult. I looked at

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing

but couldn't find anything suitable. Does anybody of you know how to unify the behavior?

Thanks,

Hendrik

Comment: It doesn't do it for me, I'm just using default settings, have you changed anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Menu:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `C#` > `Formatting` > `Spacing`

Go to `Set spacing for operators` and select `Insert space before and after binary operators`

[image]

Also in case you use extensions like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), make sure they are configured the same way as Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was ReSharper! Sorry, I didn't know ReSharper was interfering with the VS code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a german version... but in english:

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing

and set the first option for "Set spacing for operators".

Comment: I had this option set already. Apparently, ReSharper comes into play when typing ';' but not when doing CTRL-X / CTRL-V. Thanks anyway! (and no problem to read the German, haha)